# simple tables -ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint,

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have these two simple table

```
CREATE TABLE `location_main_master` (
  `location_main_master_id` bigint(16) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `city_id_test` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`location_main_master_id`,`city_id_test`),
  UNIQUE KEY `location_main_master_id_UNIQUE` (`location_main_master_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `location_sub_master` (
  `location_sub_master_id` bigint(16) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `city_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`location_sub_master_id`,`city_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `location_sub_master_id_UNIQUE` (`location_sub_master_id`),
  KEY `fk_location_sub_master_city_id_idx` (`city_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I'm trying to add a foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE `location_sub_master` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_location_sub_city_id`
  FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`)
  REFERENCES `location_main_master` (`city_id_test`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

It give me this ERROR :

> ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the order of your primary key in master table.

PRIMARY KEY (city_id_test,location_main_master_id)

So your master table should look like

*CREATE TABLE location_main_master (

   location_main_master_id BIGINT(16) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

   city_id_test INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY (city_id_test,location_main_master_id),

   UNIQUE KEY location_main_master_id_UNIQUE (location_main_master_id)

) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;*

Comment: Reference: https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/04/06/dealing-mysql-error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint/
Point (6).

Comment: Or add a key on city_id_test

Comment: Thanks guys, got it.

Comment: @GauravJ Please accept and upvote the answer if it solved your problem, so question does not remain unanswered.